# Error con java JSP

Tags: java, sql, html5, formularios, jsp

Cuando intento acceder a mi vista para agregar un nuevo producto, me vuelve a llevar a listar. No tengo ni idea de porqué se produce esto, ya que creo que todo se encuentra correcto. Adjunto el código de la vista de agregar:

**agregar.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Agregar producto</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div>
            <h1>Agregar producto</h1>
            
            <form action="Controlador">
                Nombre: <br>
                <input type="text" name="nombreForm"><br>
                Descripcion: <br>
                <input type="text" name="descripcionForm">
                Precio: <br>
                <input type="text" name="precioForm"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="accion" value="agregar">
                
            </form>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto también el código del controlador donde llamo al formulario de agregar:

**Controlador.java**

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import modeloDAO.ProductoDAO;
import models.Producto;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controlador
 */
@WebServlet("/Controlador")
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {
    
    String listar = "views/listar.jsp";
    String add = "views/agregar.jsp";
    String edit = "views/editar.jsp";
    Producto p = new Producto();
    ProductoDAO dao = new ProductoDAO();
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Controlador() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String acceso = ""; 
        String action = request.getParameter("accion");
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listar")) {
            
            acceso = listar;
            
        } else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            
            acceso = add;
            
        } else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("agregar")) {
            
            String nombre = request.getParameter("nombreForm");
            String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcionForm");
            String precio = request.getParameter("precioForm");
            p.setNombre(nombre);
            p.setDescripcion(descripcion);
            p.setPrecio(precio);
            dao.add(p);
            
            acceso = listar;
            
        }
        
        RequestDispatcher vista = request.getRequestDispatcher(acceso);
        vista.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Como digo, no veo nada incorrecto para que me llame a listar en vez de a agregar. También voy a adjuntar el código de productoDAO, por si hubiera algún error en el método add, ya que lo dudo.

**ProductoDAO.java**

```
public boolean add(Producto pro) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO producto(nombre, descripcion, precio) VALUES"
            + "('" + pro.getNombre()+"','" + pro.getDescripcion() + "','" + pro.getPrecio() + "')";
    try {
        
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

Siento si tal vez sea un error muy tonto y no lo vea, espero no molestar con estos errores... Muchas gracias de antemano al que tenga la paciencia para leerlo y responder.

Comment: Al final del bloque if asociado a `"agregar"` pone `acceso = listar;`. Supongo que se puede considerar una errata

Comment: En principio debería de redireccionarme a listar una vez se hayan agregado los datos del formulario a la base de datos. De hecho, poniendo `acceso = add` Sí me lleva al formulario, pero no me vuelve a redirigir a listar. Además, lo que introduzco no llega a registrarse en la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema no está en el controlador, pero por suerte has añadido el código del DAO. Y ahí nos encontramos con esta mala práctica:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

Tu código entra en agregar, llama al DAO que, por algún motivo, falla. Como capturas la excepción y no estás haciendo nada con ella, el fallo es ignorado y entonces se redirige al JSP `listar.jsp`. Esto te da la impresión de que se está llamando a listar, porque no se hace la inserción en la base de datos.

Por cierto, si estás usando un *prepared statement*, úsalo para parametrizar la expresión SQL y evitar *SQL injection*.

Comment: Tienes razón, ese es el error que tenía. Igualmente, ¿Porqué no me hace la inserción en la base de datos? Muchas gracias por solucionarme el otro error.

Comment: Añade en tu catch un e.printStackTrace(); y lo averiguarás

Comment: Vale, ya lo he solucionado todo. Muchas gracias de verdad.